# Sorting a combobox purely in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, sorting, combobox

I'm surprised that no one has asked this before here... well, at least I haven't found an answer here or anywhere else, actually.

I have a ComboBox that is databound to an ObservableCollection.  Everything worked great until the guys wanted the contents sorted.  No problem -- I end up changing the simple property out:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> CandyNames { get; set; } // instantiated in constructor
```

for something like this:

```
private ObservableCollection<string> _candy_names; // instantiated in constructor
public ObservableCollection<string> CandyNames
{
    get {
        _candy_names = new ObservableCollection<string>(_candy_names.OrderBy( i => i));
        return _candy_names;
    }
    set {
        _candy_names = value;
    }
}
```

This post is really two questions in one:

1. How can I sort a simple ComboBox of strings in XAML **only**.  I have researched this and can only find info about a SortDescription class, and [this is the closest implementation I could find](http://www.galasoft.ch/mydotnet/articles/article-2007081301.aspx), but it wasn't for a ComboBox.
2. Once I implemented the sorting in code-behind, it my databinding was broken; when I added new items to the ObservableCollection, the ComboBox items didn't update!  I don't see how that happened, because I didn't assign a name to my ComboBox and manipulate it directly, which is what typically breaks the binding.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use a CollectionViewSource to do the sorting in XAML, however you need to refresh it's view if the underlying collection changes.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="CBSortTest.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
    Height="300" Width="300">

    <Window.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource Source="{Binding Path=CandyNames}" x:Key="cvs">
            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                <scm:SortDescription />
            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>

    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}" />
        <Button Content="Add" Click="OnAdd" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace CBSortTest
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            CandyNames = new ObservableCollection<string>();

            OnAdd(this, null);
            OnAdd(this, null);
            OnAdd(this, null);
            OnAdd(this, null);

            DataContext = this;

            CandyNames.CollectionChanged += 
                (sender, e) =>
                {
                    CollectionViewSource viewSource =
                        FindResource("cvs") as CollectionViewSource;
                    viewSource.View.Refresh();
                };
        }

        public ObservableCollection<string> CandyNames { get; set; }

        private void OnAdd(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CandyNames.Add("Candy " + _random.Next(100));
        }

        private Random _random = new Random();
    }
}
```

Comment: cool, that's definitely a possibility.  I had just found this article http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=17 so it's good to hear that CollectionViewSource is my likely solution.  However, I think this will work without refreshing...  thanks for the tip!

Comment: can anyone explain the difference between ItemsSource="{StaticResource cvs}" and ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}"?  I always considered StaticResource to imply that there was a binding, so I just have a conceptual hurdle to jump regarding why Binding needs to be specified and is not implicit?