# Sort by multiple items in itemtemlate

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, wpfdatagrid

All,

I have the following class

```
public class MyCoolClass
{
    public string Field1{ get; set; }
    public int? Field2{ get; set; }
}
```

I have another class

```
public class MyOtherClass
{
    ///a bunch of neat properties
    public MyCoolClass CoolClass { get; set; }
}
```

I have a Collection of MyOtherClass that I bind to:
C#:

```
public ObservableCollection<MyOtherClass> MyCoolDataSource { get; }
```

XAML:

```
<GroupBox DataContext="{Binding Path=MyCoolDataSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Header="Test DataGrid">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <!--A bunch of neat fields-->
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="CoolClass" SelectedItem={"Binding Path=CoolClass, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}">
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemTemplate>
                    <!--DataTemplate that shows all properties of MyCoolClass-->
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemTemplate>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</GroupBox>
```

Now, my question is, let's say I want the option to sort by a certain field (using .Net 4.0).  In WPF, this is no problem, we just use SortMemberPath.  However, let's say I want to sort by all fields in MyCoolClass for the CoolClass column in my DataGrid.  Is this possible to do purely from XAML, or am I stuck with creating a property in C# that combines the two fields for the purposes of sorting?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you had a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274690/sorting-a-combobox-purely-in-xaml

It might help.

Comment: Interesting.  I have two issues, though.  1) How would this work with the DataGrid (I should add that sort needs to be on-demand), and 2) For some reason, even though I have WindowsBase referenced, and even though I can see in the ObjectBrowser that there is a System.ComponentModel in the WindowsBase library, I seem to be having trouble declaring the System.ComponentModel namespace for assembly WindowsBase in my xaml.  If I try to use xmlns:smc="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase" WindowsBase, I get an undefined CLR namespace o-O.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Linq. I have replaced ObservableCollection with List, but the logic should be the same..

```
List<MyOtherClass> MyCoolDataSource = new List<MyOtherClass>();

MyCoolDataSource.Add(new MyOtherClass { CoolClass = new MyCoolClass { Field1 = "Z", Field2 = 123 } });
MyCoolDataSource.Add(new MyOtherClass { CoolClass = new MyCoolClass { Field1 = "A", Field2 = 3 } });
MyCoolDataSource.Add(new MyOtherClass { CoolClass = new MyCoolClass { Field1 = "J", Field2 = 4 } });
MyCoolDataSource.Add(new MyOtherClass { CoolClass = new MyCoolClass { Field1 = "K" } });

var sortedByField1 = MyCoolDataSource.OrderBy(e => e.CoolClass.Field1).ToList();
var sortedByField2 = MyCoolDataSource.OrderBy(e => e.CoolClass.Field2).ToList();

//display
Console.WriteLine("Ordered by first filed");
sortedByField1.ForEach(e => {
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Field 1: {0}, Field 2: {1}", e.CoolClass.Field1, e.CoolClass.Field2));
});

Console.WriteLine("Ordered by second filed");
sortedByField2.ForEach(e => {
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Field 1: {0}, Field 2: {1}", e.CoolClass.Field1, e.CoolClass.Field2));
});
```

Comment: Just now only noted that you require an XAML solution.. my above solution can not be counted in that case, sorry for that

Comment: Ya.  The idea is that the sort takes place in the view without effecting the way the underlying data is queried.  If I wanted to use Linq, then I would just use OrderBy and ThenBy.