# Adding Append feature to WPF Combobox

Tags: wpf, vb.net, combobox

I've just moved across from a standard WinForm to a WPF, I have added a combo box to my program but I want to add an append feature and alphabetical ordering to the combo box. Within a standard VB project I can simply go under the properties of the combo box but when it comes to WPF I cannot find it, I'm taking an educated guess and saying I have to program it in. My question is how would achieve this goal?

Comment: How have you defined your combobox?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting a combobox purely in XAML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274690/sorting-a-combobox-purely-in-xaml)

Comment: Apologies I don't think I worded it correctly, all I want to do is when the user clicks the combo box it will show my list but it will be alphabetical order and when you type into the combo box it will predict the result you want for example start writing Unit  and predicts all result beginning with Unit. Currently in any standard VB program you can go into the properties of the combo box and simply add these features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) :

```
 Dim source = New ObservableCollection(Of String)
 source.Add("item 1")
 source.Add("item 2")
 source.Add("item 3")
 source.Add("item 4")
 comboBox1.ItemsSource = source
```

And each time you want to add something you should add it to the collection instate.

**EDIT**

if you want your list to be alphabetical sorted one possibe way is to use a simple List

```
Dim source = New List(Of String)
Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)


    source.Add("item 1")
    source.Add("item 2")
    source.Add("item 4")
    source.Add("item 3")

    source.Sort()

    'the combobox can autocomplete the user typing
    comboBox1.IsEditable = True
    comboBox1.IsTextSearchEnabled = True

    comboBox1.ItemsSource = source
End Sub
```

and on the button click event you code should be the following

```
 If (txt.Text <> "") Then
        source.Add(txt.Text)
        source.Sort()
        txt.Text = ""
        comboBox1.ItemsSource = Nothing

        comboBox1.ItemsSource = source
  End If
```

hope this can help

Comment: Apologies I don't think I worded it correctly, all I want to do is when the user clicks the combo box it will show my list but it will be alphabetical order and when you type into the combo box it will predict the result you want for example start writing Unit and predicts all result beginning with Unit. Currently in any standard VB program you can go into the properties of the combo box and simply add these features.

Comment: i updated the answer, please try to test it and let me know this was helpful